# Sockets not working

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to make a simple client and server for sending and receiving text. Client waits for command line input and then sends it to server which displays it on `System.out`. But the server gets stuck at reading from socket although the client allows me to type next line to send.

Client:

```
public class Main implements Runnable{
    String [] args;
    Socket socket;
     PrintWriter printer;

    public Main(String [] args){
        this.args = args;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
            printer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e){
            System.out.println("Unknown host.");
            System.exit(2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true){
            String textToSend = System.console().readLine();
            printer.print(textToSend);
        }
    }
}
```

The line `printer.print(textToSend);` does not work.

Server:

```
public class Main implements Runnable{
    String [] args;

    public Main(String [] args){
        this.args = args;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (args == null){
            System.out.println("Argument for port missing");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        try {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

            while (true){
                Socket client = listener.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connected");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                try{
                    while(true){
                        String text = in.readLine();
                        System.out.println(text);
                        if (in.read() == -1){
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Client lost");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would have been welcome.

Comment: Be specific.  What "doesn't work"?  Do you get an error?  What do your stack traces actually tell you?

Comment: I don't even get any stack traces. The text is just never received.

Comment: does your `run` for your server even get run?

Comment: @ScaryWombat 1. It does (from main(String [] args) to get rid of `static` modifier). 2. It prints stuff I write in `System.in`

Comment: see my answer for an update

Comment: See my answer for the solution

Comment: Sockets stopped working - what will happen to Java now? :)

Comment: You must always close the streams and socket in a finally block in pre Java 7 code. From Java 7 onwards, you can use the try with resources statement instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error: You have to add the newline character and call flush:

```
      printer.print(textToSend + "\n");
      printer.flush();
```

This works for me.

Flush forces to send all the data and empty all the buffers so data is send. The newline is needed, so that the receiving end knows the line is complete.

Your check to see if no data was send should be `line == null`, not `read() == -1`.

This is my whole demo code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while(true){
    String textToSend = null;
    try {
       textToSend = reader.readLine();
       System.out.println("read text: " + textToSend);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    printer.print(textToSend + "\n");
    printer.flush();
    System.out.println("text send");
 }
```

Error check on the server side:

```
    String text = in.readLine();
    if (text == null){
          return;
    }
    System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: I started the server, then started the client. Entered "Hallo" in the client console and hit enter. Text appeared on the server console.

Comment: What I also changed was the use of the console

Comment: Yep works for me now (forgot to rebuild). But it's also true that it's throwing one char away.

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing

```
 if (in.read() == -1){
    return;
 }
```

you are throwing away one char

Also, when you are writing

```
printer.print(textToSend);
```

the textToSend does not have a `CR` so the receiving `readLine` will block.
Try adding a `CR` to the end of `textToSend` or use the `println` method

Comment: Even if I send more then one char nothing is received.

Comment: Ah, you found the error the same time I did, nice (-:

Comment: If there was a char to be read, then it would read it, and as it is not being saved, then I call that `throwing it away`

Comment: Yes of course. What he would need to do is to check, if the line is null.